# Selecting data from 2 different databases and comparing them

Tags: sql

Forgive me if this question has already been asked, but... I'm trying to select data from 2 different tables in a database and count all the data in one table that is equal to the data in the second table if that makes sense? Below is the code I am trying to use

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM client_id, clientid, COUNT(client_id) FROM enquiry, check_s WHERE client_id = clientid";
```

Comment: Do you mean each record - column for column in table 1 being exactly the same as that in table 2?
Your query is simply counting the number of matching Client Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query appears to be syntactically wrong. 
What you can try is to join the two tables on a primary key(id?) and any other fields you're trying to match. The basic syntax would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
DB1.Table1 
JOIN DB2.Table2 
ON DB1.Table1.PrimaryKey = DB2.Table2.PrimaryKey;
```

If you're looking for an exact data match, you may have to join the tables based on all fields(in the `ON` clause in the above query).

Edit:

Now that you've explained it, you can try this:

```
SELECT table1.*, count(*) as `n` FROM table1
JOIN table2 
ON table1.field = table2.field;
```

Again, if you need to compare more fields, just include them in the `ON` clause, and set conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Not sure if I made it clear enough. I have 2 tables in 1 database. The first table has multiple records already in it. The second table has a single record entered into it from one form. What I want to do is count how many records are in the first table that are equal to the record in the second table e.g. Table 1 contains the word 'apple' 50 times, the second table has 1 record entered and one of the columns contains 'apple'. I want the query to take the word in the second table, and count how many times it's in the first table. hope this makes it clearer?

Comment: And in your output you want a number? Like 50? OR the whole row + the number

Comment: @JakeNeal Yes, that's clearer. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath Can I swap out "apple" for table1.field ? There isn't going to be a specific value as it is in a while loop

Comment: If there's going to be no specific value, remove the WHERE clause altogether, and include more OR's in the `ON` clause. example: `...ON table1.field = table2.field1 OR table1.field = table2.field2 OR table1.field = table2.field3`

Comment: My example basically gives you the syntax of `JOIN`. You'll have to modify it depending on what columns of table2 you need to compare with what columns of table1. Is it ANY field in table2 compared with ANY field of table1? Or fieldname to fieldname comparison? Etc!

If you're still having trouble, just post the exact table structure of the two tables and I can write the query for you.

Comment: There is only 1 field in table2 compared to 1 field in table1. The field in table1 (enquiry) is client_id and the field in table2 (check_s) is clientid

Comment: Then it's very simple, just remove the WHERE clause from my above query. I'll re-edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

Lets say your main table name is Client and your secondary table (from the form) is Enquiry and the column which you want to compare in client is called client_id and the same column in Enquiry is called clientid.
Then you have

```
Select Count(Client.*)
From Client, Enquiry
Where Client.client_id = Enquiry.clientid
Group by Client.client_id
```